# Remove IPv6 addresses from a list using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, avahi

Using avahi I have populated a list of ip-addresses on my network range. The information populated is then refined using sed to give the following output

```
Initial data = address = [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Refined data = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The command to do so is as follows:

```
avahi-browse -alrt | grep -w address | sort -u | sed -e 's/address = //' | sed -e 's/\[//' | sed -e 's/\]//'
```

This works correctly most of the time however on the odd occasion addresses such as xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
 are displayed in the list and I would like to omit them.

I know I could possibly use a regex expression or something to ensure the data always matches a valid ip i.e xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but I am unsure as to how to go about this. Any help is much appreciated.

The command is run on linux using a bash script and I wish it to return only the valid ip addresses in the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format.

Comment: Just FYI, those "odd" addresses are IPv6 addresses.

Comment: I assumed that would be the case however in the initial display without parsing the info from avahi it says it is an IPv4 address for some reason. Ps I didnt call the addresses odd, just that they are only displayed on the odd occasion ;)

Comment: Why do you want that? These addresses are the future!

Comment: Because the project this is being used has no support, as of yet, for anything other than IPv4 and none is planned for the close future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your 3 sed commands with this one:

```
sed 's/address = \[\|\]//g'
```

OR:

```
sed -r 's/address = \[|\]//g'
```

**EDIT:** To remove invalid IPs also use this sed:

```
sed -r -e 's/address = \[|\]//g' -e 's/= +([^:]+\:){5,}.*$/=/' file
```

Comment: Still displays IP addresses that dont match xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format

Comment: Yes I am updating answer in a min.

Comment: Strange, it doesnt work when I add it to the bash script. The IPv6 addresses still get added to the list

Comment: Can you provide your input data in your question for which it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the file slightly and this way now suits my use case. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your three `sed` commands with following one

```
sed -nr 's/.*address = \[(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\].*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
avahi-browse -alrt | sed -n "/address/ s/address = \[\(\([012]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\.\)\{3\}[12]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\)\].*/\1/p" | sort -u
```

sort could be done before but is certainly faster after the sed and grep is not needed because sed could also filter the lines. (not tested because not shell here)